# TryUpdateModelAsync rejects null naviagation properties?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

`TryUpdateModelAsync()` seems to reject my model objects if the navigation property is null, even though the foreign key is properly set.

For example, it won't accept a Book if AuthorId is set, but Author is null:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a complete working example showing the problem of this behavior:

```
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Model:

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger<EditModel> _logger;

    [BindProperty] public Book Book { get; set; }
    public List<Author> Authors {get; set;}

    public EditModel(YourDbContext context, ILogger<EditModel> logger)
    {
        _context = context;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null) { return NotFound(); }

        Book = await _context.Books.Include(b => b.Author).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (Book == null) { return NotFound(); }

        Authors = await _context.Authors.ToListAsync();
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id)
    {
        var bookToUpdate = await _context.Books.FindAsync(id);
        if (bookToUpdate == null) { return NotFound(); }

        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Book>(bookToUpdate, "book", b => b.Title, b => b.AuthorId))
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
        else 
        {
            foreach (var modelStateKey in ModelState.Keys)
            {
                var modelStateVal = ModelState[modelStateKey];
                foreach (var error in modelStateVal.Errors)
                {
                    _logger.LogError($"Key: {modelStateKey}, Error: {error.ErrorMessage}");
                }
            }
        }
        Book = bookToUpdate;
        return RedirectToPage(new { id});
    }
}
```

Razor Page:

```
@page
@model EditModel

<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Book.Id" />
    <input asp-for="Book.Title" />
    <select asp-for="Book.AuthorId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Authors,"Id","Name"))"></select>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

The modelstate will always have errors complaining:

```
Key: Book.Author, Error: The Author field is required.
```

This is obviously a simplified example, but in general there can be many large navigation properties, and so populating them all is not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .Net 6 or higher versions, it would enable  nullable reference types atuomaticlly in your csproj file:

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

The property

```
public Author Author { get; set; }
```

would be considered as non-nullable

And as mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#non-nullable-reference-types-and-required-attribute):

> The validation system treats non-nullable parameters or bound
> properties as if they had a [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
> attribute.

If you want to keep it as non-nullable,the solution for MVC projects:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(
    options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);
```

In Razor Page projects,you could try:

```
builder.Services.Configure<MvcOptions>(x=>x.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes=true);
```

I tried on myside and it works :
[image]